# Convert numpy array shape from (1, 100 ) to (100, ) in python

Tags: python

I have a np.array that I want to store it in a mat file and then to load it from my code. The code for storing it to mat file is the following:

```
data = {'reduced_train_face': reduced_train_face.tolist(),
        'reduced_train_audio': reduced_train_audio.tolist(),
        'reduced_audio_labels': reduced_audio_labels.tolist()}

m4p.savemat('data.mat', data)
```

And then the code for retrieving the info is the following:

```
reduced_audio_labels = np.array(data['reduced_audio_labels'])
```

I have noticed that the type of file is changing. The file before the loading was of type:

[image]

and when I loaded the file:

[image]

That change cause me several issues. How can I convert  : (1, 100 ) to   : (100, )??

Comment: why are you saving your arrays using `.tolist()` instead of directly saving the arrays themselves?

Comment: Apparently does not work otherwrise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.squeeze(reduced_audio_labels)
```

will remove superfluous dimensions

Comment: What is the significance of going from (1,100) to (100,)?

Comment: Some libraries' methods _really_ care about this difference between 1- and 2-dimension vectors (e.g. for machine learning applications), even though, as you may be suggesting, it doesn't intuitively feel like they should be too different.